# What's the meaning of "若者の価値観は社会的な影響が強いです。"?

Tags: grammar

I have been learning Japanese for about 9 months and can understand the basic grammar in this sentence well, but the meaning of it seems **ambiguous** to me, and I wonder *which* meaning below is right, and *how* can I adjust the sentence to express the other meaning?
(1) The young people's value has a strong influence on the society.
(2) The young people's value is strongly influenced by the society.
Or, neither is right?

P.S.
I **have used** google translation and it tells me the first one is right, but my teacher has a different idea.
Any thought will be appreciated. Especially IF you are a native Japanese speaker, your answer will be more convincing and may you tell me about that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a native speaker and I took this sentence as (2) intuitively. (So anything below is more of an afterthought.)

Technically speaking, this sentence is indeed ambiguous, and 社会的な影響 probably means "influence **on** the society" more often than "influence **by** the society". Still, 価値観 is something personal, and it is not usually regarded as something that affects the society, at least directly.

FWIW, DeepL Translate [did translate](https://www.deepl.com/translator#ja/en/%E8%8B%A5%E8%80%85%E3%81%AE%E4%BE%A1%E5%80%A4%E8%A6%B3%E3%81%AF%E7%A4%BE%E4%BC%9A%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AA%E5%BD%B1%E9%9F%BF%E3%81%8C%E5%BC%B7%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%80%82) this as "The values of young people are strongly influenced by society." Compare it with 消費税の増税は社会的な影響が強いです, which was translated by DeepL as "The consumption tax hike has a strong social impact."

To express (2) unambiguously:

- 若者の価値観は社会**からの**影響が強いです。
- 若者の価値観は社会**による**影響が強いです。
- 若者の価値観**に**社会**が**与える影響は強いです。
- 若者の価値観は社会**から**強い影響を**受けます**。

To express (1) unambiguously:

- 若者の価値観は社会**への**影響が強いです。
- 若者の価値観**が**社会**に**与える影響は強いです。
- 若者の価値観は社会**に**強い影響を与えます。

(You can use 及ぼす instead of 与える.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice and enlightening answer! Especially the part about "whether something is personal or public will affect the sense of the sentence" is absolutely helpful and insightful.

Comment: @曹子尧 Note that there is no such a "rule". Both (1) and (2) make sense depending on the context. It's just that I have seen sentences like (2) many times before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a native speaker (which I say merely because you seem to believe that will change the value of my contribution).

But that being said, let's parse this sentence piece by piece.

> 若者の価値観は社会的な影響が強いです

To do that let's simplify it a bit to

> 影響が強いです。

which means "its influence is strong" or "it has a strong influence".

Now let's build this up gradually.

> 何かは影響が強いです。

Which like above we could translate as either
"Something's influence is strong" or "Something has a strong influence."

> 何かは社会的な影響が強いです。

"Something has a strong societal influence".

And finally,

> 若者の価値観

Let's simplify this a bit too to

> 若者の価値

This would mean simply "the value of youth (young people)".  But, when we tack on 観 it gets a little harder to translate this.  観 means "view, perspective" or, by extension "how we regard" (think of the root meaning of *regard* in English as to *look*).  So, for

> 若者の価値観

I'll go with "How we regard worth of our youth".

Now putting everything back together we get

> 若者の価値観は社会的な影響が強いです

> How we view the value of our young people has a strong societal effect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I asked for telling me whether you are a native speaker just because I want to convince my teacher lol, and it doen't change the value of any answer.
However, in my view, 価値観 is a whole word, which means one's judgement about what is valueble and what isn't (I'm a Chinese and it seems almost obvious for me). Maybe you can take this into consideration, and will get a different explanation?

Comment: @曹子尧 Thank you.  That's very useful information.  I hadn't really thought of it that way.  I'll rethink my answer.